# Pandas str.contains regex

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to learn Pandas and MatPlotLib. As a challenge I decided it would be fun to try and graph the results of profession type based on the comments. My thought process is to get comments, find a small dataset of professions, and check the comment against the dataset. I'm sure there has to be a better way, still learning.

**Is there a difference in how Pandas regex matches compared to regular regex results? `0` should be true should it not?**

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import praw

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='my_cool_application')
submissions = r.get_submission(submission_id = '2owaba')
s = pd.Series(submissions.comments)

pattern = r'Programmer'
print (s.str.contains(pattern))
print (s)
```

Output is not as expected.

```
$ python reddit.py 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
10   NaN
11   NaN
12   NaN
13   NaN
14   NaN
...
57   NaN
58   NaN
59   NaN
60   NaN
61   NaN
62   NaN
63   NaN
64   NaN
65   NaN
66   NaN
67   NaN
68   NaN
69   NaN
70   NaN
71   NaN
Length: 72, dtype: float64
0     Programmer/Project Lead for a railroad company...
1     I deliver pizza part time while I go to colleg...
2      Graduate student (molecular biologist) + cat mom
3     Systems Analyst at a big, boring corporation. ...
4     I work in IT.  I wear many hats at my (small) ...
5                       I'm a professional desk jobber.
6     medical pot producer....pretty much your typic...
7     Research tech for the federal govt. Water leve...
8                                     Karate instructor
9     I own a Vape shop and an E-Liquid manufacturin...
10      Guidance counselor. If only my students knew...
11                         Graduate student and chemist
12    Regulatory Affairs for a medical device manufa...
13    restaurant manager (for the moment, looking to...
14    Logistics and technician manager for a radon m...
...
57    Technical Support for a big credit card proces...
58    Class action settlement administration. Been t...
59    IT Consultant here 8) Lot's of IT folk at EF i...
60    This'll be my first year, staying in the Back ...
61    Research assistant in the epidemiology departm...
62    IT undergrad and this will be my second time a...
63    Commercial construction foreman at a tiny company
64    I'm actually a web developer for a company tha...
65             Install cameras, tv's and phone systems.
66    Animation/design/anything creative. Graduated ...
67                                     Career bartender
68    I work in the Traveling Hospitality Business f...
69    Assisstant Manager at a major retail chain...t...
70                                          Barista :) 
71    Hi, I'm Pasquale Rotella (CEO, Insomniac Event...
Length: 72, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series contains `praw.objects.Comment` objects not strings. Extracting body should give you what you want:

```
s = pd.Series(comment.body for comment in submissions.comments)
```